# Suse Linux kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, suse

I am unable to understand the porting of patches from Linux kernel to Suse distribution.
Looks like that the SuSE doesn't maintain the kernel version as per upstream, or have their own way of maintaining the kernel version.

For example, a change in the kernel API was done in the kernel as:
File include/linux/fs.h in kernel version v4.13.16, is:

```
extern ssize_t kernel_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t);
```

In kernel version v4.14 is:

```
extern ssize_t kernel_write(struct file *, const void *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

The developers then can use the `KERNEL_VERSION` macro to distinguish which one to use.

```
#if KERNEL_VERSION(4, 14, 0) < LINUX_VERSION_CODE
      ret = kernel_write(file_ptr, &value, 1, &position);
#else
      ret = kernel_write(file_ptr, &value, 1, position);
#endif
```

However this does not work in SuSE kernel. I see that in the SuSE kernel version 4.12.14-195, the patch from v4.14 is included.

So how do driver developers cope with such mismatch? Is there a special macro used in SuSE linux?

Comment: Is it included by SuSE or they took stable kernel with the patch? But main document to read is this: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/convincing-your-manager-upstreaming-their-best-interest/ and this https://kernelnewbies.org/UpstreamMerge

Comment: @0andriy Agreed to the point.